# Regex validation: don't allow both 'a' and 'b' in text

Tags: regex, validation

can you please help me with regex to verify that text does not contains both A and B at the same time.

Single or multiple occurrences of A or B only is fine. 
No occurrences is fine too.

Thanks

Comment: please provide sample input and pass-fail indications.

Comment: Also tell us which language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as: contains only characters that are not `A` OR contains only characters that are not `B`: ([De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

```
([^B]*)|([^A]*)
```

Comment: Thanks @nick-whaley, I came up with 
`^(([^;]*)|([^,]*))$`
`z,y,x` and `x;y;z` should pass but `x,y;z` - not

Comment: @Nick you don't need parentheses

Comment: Props on the De Morgan's laws!